# URL Rewriting For Dynamic Pages Based on URL Variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page called `foo.php` which is sending URL variable `id` to `bar.php` like

```
<?php
  echo '<a href="www.domain.com/bar.php?id=1">Comedy</a>';
  echo '<a href="www.domain.com/bar.php?id=2">Family</a>';
?>
```

and in the `bar.php` I have

```
<?php
  $id = (int)$_GET['id']
  "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id";
?>
```

which as you can see the result will be presentation of Comedy items or Family items base on the link that user clicked on `foo.php` page
now in both case the URL looks very ugly like

> www.domain.com/bar.php?id=1

or

> www.domain.com/bar.php?id=2

now can you please help me to figure it out how I can use the `/comedy` instead of having `bar.php?id=1` or `/family` instead of `bar.php?id=2`?

this looks easy with `mod-rewrite` since there are only 2 items here but what if we have many?! is there any dynamic way to take care of this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96095/discussion-on-question-by-behseini-url-rewriting-for-dynamic-pages-based-on-url).

Comment: @EdCottrell making use of the new super powers already i see, its ok i voted for you.

Comment: This is still not working!